# Dealing With Simple Inequalities

Tags: inequality

This is an odd question that may have to do with my lack of mathematical background prior to the study of the so-called "higher" mathematics.

Say I have two pieces of information
$$ a+b<1 \text{ and } b<1$$
How do I easily find that $a\in \mathbb R$ (as in I can choose any value of $a$, as I will always be able to find $b$ that suits both inequalities)

Or, alternatively
$$a+b<5 \text{ and } b>1$$
Which yields $a<4$

It takes me ridiculous amount of time to work these out (I consider $\sim 10-20$ seconds ridiculous for such a rudimentary operation).

Is there some simple method of dealing with these? How do you do it? Preferably one that can later be generalized in any such simple case (change $a+b$ for $a-b$, change $<$ and $>$ etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: Take $b$ at its extremes and consider the implications for $a$.  So in the first case $b$ could be almost $1$ or very negative, meaning $a$ could be anything negative or very positive or less, so it yields any value for $a$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle the first is to rewrite it as
$$ a < 1 - b. \tag{1}$$
Now, at least, $a$ is isolated, and we just need to determine information about the right hand side. In particular, how large can it be?

We know that $b < 1$, or rather that $-b > 1$. There are no other restrictions, so $-b$ can be arbitrarily large. And so the right hand side of $(1)$ can be arbitrarily large. Thus $a$ can be arbitrarily large.

More honestly, the next question is how large we can make the right hand side. A quick glance at the other inequality lets me decide that we can make the right hand side arbitrarily large.

I don't know if this is quicker or slower than what you do in your head. It's (in particular, the second) is approximately what I thought about in my head, and I decided that it was true very very quickly.